# How do I make modal buttons appear inside the modal body?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

How do I make modal buttons ("OK", "DISMISS", etc) appear inside the modal body instead of the footer?
Because I set a photo as a background I'd like the buttons floating above this photo.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="modal1 fade" 
                    id="XXX" 
                    tabindex="-1" 
                    aria-labelledby="XXX" 
                    role="dialog" 
                    aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal_wrapper1">
        <div class="modal-dialog1">
        <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="Ximage" alt="image" />
        <a href="" target="_blank" class="btn">button!</a>
        <a href="" type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

.modal1{ 
        width: 100%; 
        position: fixed; 
        text-align: center; 
        margin: 0px auto; top: 0px; 
        left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; 
        z-index: 1050; 
        }
.modal_wrapper1{ 
        display: table; 
        overflow: auto; 
        overflow-y: scroll; 
        height: 100%; 
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; outline: 0; 
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px auto;
        }
.modal-dialog1{
        margin-top: 0px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 0px 20px;
        }
```

Comment: If you're saying you want the buttons above the photo, then all you would need to do is move the `<a>` tags up above your `<img>` tag. Its hard to say with such a small code snippet though.

Answer (score 0):

I have used same thing to display button in the same section, with background and control placed on it, you can try similar to this in your page. Its working fine for me.
You can change background to apply to your section instead of body.

```
    <body style="background-image: url('../../abc.jpg'); align-content:center;">
        <header style="height:200px">
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 text-center">
                        <div id="login" name="loginForm" >
                            <input ........ /><br /><br />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Continue" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
```

If you are using bootstrap, than it will be better if you use the default css instead of modifying it too much, as it will affect the placement of controls when screen have different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding an `<img>` inside the modal-body `div`, apply it as a background image in your css.

```
.modal1 .modal-body {
  background:url(Ximage) no-repeat;
  background-size:contain; // or auto or cover, whichever works best.
}
```